# How to display oracle blob type image in Codeigniter?

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

I'm trying to display image to my website that is stored in Oracle database as datatype BLOB. I am using Codeigniter for develop my site. I tried many ways, but I got nothing. Can someone please specify me what will be the Controller code, model code, and view?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When loading oracle blobs I have had to use it like this

```
$results['blob_data']->load();
```

The `->load()` is an object that is passed back from the oci8 methods.

Comment: Thanks for contributing with me but I used "->load()" for showing text data. its working for display text from BLOB datatype field but not working for stored image as blob datatype. I need to display image, which is stored in Oracle database as BLOB datatype.